# upload file using shared link using Microsoft graph API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am able to get all files in folder using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/{SharedUrl}/root/children

but not able to upload file.

When i am trying to upload file it is throwing error:

"error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Unsupported segment type.

Is it possible to upload files using api https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/{SharedUrl}  ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload files using the shares endpoint. You need to [upload files](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_createuploadsession) directly to the drive you want to store them.